# Family not satisfying uniform equicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Suppose that a family of homeomorphisms $f_n$ from the compact metric space $(X,d)$ to the compact metric space $(Y,d')$ is not uniformly equicontinuous. Does this imply that there exists two different points $x,y$ and a subsequence $n_j$ such that $d'(f_{n_j}(x),f_{n_{j}}(y))\rightarrow 0$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: what do you mean by uniform continuity?! note that each $f_n$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: If so it seems for some point $a$ in $Y$, both $f_{n_j}(x)$ and $f_{n_j}(y)$ will converge to $a$.